# Do I call my supervisor “dean” or “professor”?

Tags: advisor, etiquette, titles

My supervisor is the dean of an engineering department at my university. Should I address him as *Dean Smith* or *Professor Smith?* Personally, *dean* sounds a little clunky for me talking to my faculty supervisor but I’ve been using it so far, and he hasn’t really mentioned anything about it.

**Is it normal to address someone as *dean* or should I start using *professor* instead?**

Also, I don’t know if he’s the type to care about such things.

Comment: ask him, but keep in mind that it might change depending on the context/people around/"hat he is wearing".

Comment: What's wrong with his first name? "Hi, Bob!" is a lot less clunky than "Hi, Dean Smith!" (unless of course his first name *is* Dean...)

Comment: We're not close enough yet for me to use his first name.

Comment: It looks quite awkward for a student to address his supervisor as "dean".

Comment: What country is this in?

Comment: This is in the US.

Comment: If you are a grad student in the US you are close enough for first names.

Comment: I just called my supervisor 'sir' for the duration of my project. We got on really well and probably *could* have been on a first name basis, but I was never explicitly told what to call him so I erred on the side of caution. He never mentioned it, it wasn't weird at all, and the project went great.

Comment: I'm in undergrad. We've never met in person, which is why I'm thinking we're not on first name basis yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the title that is appropriate for your interaction:

- Prof Smith - anything related to his or her role as an educator or researcher
- Dean Smith (or Provost Smith, etc) - anything related to his or her role as an administrator

Many times when people become deans, deanlets, or provosts, they stop teaching and actively conducting research - which makes it easy to refer to them in their administrative role only.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to ask him directly (the easy solution), you could always ask other students what they do.  In general, I would stick to "Professor Smith."  People don't have be called by their full titles (I would never want or expect to be called "Associate Professor Webster").

Answer (score 1):

In my experience there is no context at all where you would address or refer to someone as Dean Smith because they are a dean. 'Dean' is a job-title (like 'accountant'), whereas 'Professor' is (also) a person-title (like Mr.).

Personally I'd say if you're not yet close enough to your supervisor to call them by their first name, it's time you got to know your supervisor better. After all, http://phdcomics.com/comics/archive.php?comicid=1296

Comment: This is wrong or at best institution and rank specific.  As a professor, I do use formal titles when talking to senior administrators at my R1. Partly this is to remind them of their administrative responsibilities and to avoid false chumminess.

Comment: @RoboKaren I would refer to someone as 'the Dean'. Or potentially address them as 'Dean', but never as 'Dean Smith'.

Comment: "Dear Dean Smith: I am writing as a the Chair of Widget Studies. I must protest your recent decision as our divisional dean to not allocate another FTE to our department. We must make more widgets. Signed, Robo Karen, Chair, Widget Studies; Professor of Widget Studies"

Comment: I will also when speaking at university-wide faculty meetings, use formal titles (Dean Smith; Provost Doe) especially and particularly when referring to (aka protesting) policies implemented by those individuals.  So it's not just written correspondence but oral locution: "Fellow faculty, Dean Smith's regrettable decision to cut FTEs from the entire widget and gadget division has caused irreparable harm to our great university. Dean Smith, would you care to explain what your rationale was for this?"

Comment: Please note that I'm a professor (just not of widget studies, oh I wish I were though). As a graduate student, you'd only really interact with a Dean-as-Dean in very restricted cases (filing a grievance; protesting university-wide policy; escalation of a complaint; etc). If you modify your answer to clarify that you mean "[almost] no context ... as a student" then I think you're pretty close to accurate.

Answer (score 0):

One of your comments on the question is vital:

I'm in [sic] undergrad. **We've never met in person, which is why I'm thinking we're not on first name basis yet.** (Emphasis mine)

I would refer to him as Professor Smith as I agree Dean Smith sounds clunky. Once you build a relationship with him, this nay change to a first name basis but you don't appear to be to that stage yet.

Comment: And when I say you're a "sick undergrad" I mean it in the colloquial "awesome" sense ;)